# Wordpress Plugin with Custom Post

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I created wordpress plugin for custom post type like book. Now i need to add page template in custom post type but page template selection box is missing. Please tell me how to add page template selection box in custom post type.
Please help me for solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set  template in only "Page" type post type.
To set template for your Post type "book" you can it as

1. create page for it.
   2  then set template for this page.
2. and at last publish it.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks for answer i got my mistake Thax